# Want to fetch URL data using Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, asynchronous

`http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK&appid=XXXXXXXXX`

this is The link which displays the Historical weather of London

I want ajax call in Laravel 5.3 to display data retrieved by above link.

is anyone knowing how to make an Asynchronous call in laravel + Ajax

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery?

Comment: Always show what you did? What's the error? So you will get specific answer

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel Async you can use [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues)

Implementation will be something like this

Make a new job it will contain

```
public function handle()
    {
        $appid = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

        $url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK&appid=" . $appid;
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

        dd($json);
        //DO_SOMTHING_IN_YOUR_JSON
    }
```

Please be aware that this method will run in the background.

For JS Ajax request (suppose you import jQuery)

```
var appId = YOUR_APP_ID;
var url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK&appid=" + appId;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function( response) {
        //DO_SOMTHING_WITH_YOUR_JSON
    }
});
```

Comment: For `JS` you can execute the above code in your browser's console, for `PHP` just try to put the current code in any `php` script, it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK&appid=XXXXXXXXX',
    success: function( response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

You can then change the URL to whatever you want. Be it laravel or directly to the wather API.

If you make the call to Laravel, then in Laravel, use Guzzle to make the call to the weather API and do whatever you want to with the result in the controller.

Comment: is there any valid working for above question?
because I am Unable to do that you are saying .